# Jquery DataTables server parameters

Tags: jquery, datatables

In jquery DataTables it is possible to add server parameters through the method `fnServerData` or `fnServerParams` :

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({ 

 "bServerSide": true,
 "sAjaxSource": contextApp,

"fnServerParams" : function(aoData){
    aoData.push("name":"paramName", "value":"paramValue");
}
)
```

Is it possible to do the same thing through `fnSettings` method?

For example :

```
var myTable = $("#myTable").dataTable();
var oSettings  = myTable.fnSettings();
//add server paramters to oSettings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible since you can manipulate "aoServerParams" in oSettings - but why would you want to do this? Its not part of the public API (and although it isn't like to change in 1.x, it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

```
var myTable = $("#myTable").dataTable();
myTable.fnSettings().aoServerParams.push({"sName": "user",
                                          "fn": function (aoData) {
                                             aoData.push({
                                               "name": "titre",
                                               "value": titre
                                             });
                                          }});
```